# JS function not being reached

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have a JavaScript file to work with Google JavaScript API for maps however the function is not doing anything its like its not being reached any help is appreciated thanks

```
window.onload = function() {

    alert("Hi!");
    var map;
    function initMap() {
      alert("Function reached!");
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: initMap isn't being called anywhere in the code you posted - you've declared the function but you haven't run it

Comment: Have you called the function after defining it?

Comment: the file above is called map.js I then have this code in my html file <script type="text/javascript" src="map.js" /></script>

Comment: could you please add fiddle link

Comment: The function is now being reached just have to get the map working now thanks

Answer (score -1):

try executing your `initMap` function afterwards (or when it is needed)

```
window.onload = function() {

  alert("Hi!");
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    alert("Function reached!");
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  };
  initMap();
}
```

Comment: yeah function is being reached